# Slick images under div

Tags: jquery, css

I want to display images in slick carousel with center mode and infinite
it is working fine. but slick track is go out of div.
i need to display it inside div.
Please check the below image.

any one have an solution to fix this?

[image]

**Jquery:**

```
  $(".slickImage").slick({
                    centerMode: true,
                    infinite: true,
                    autoplay: false,
                    centerPadding: '0px',
                    slidesToShow: 1,
                    arrows: true
                });
```

**view:**

```
<div class="slider-section2">
                        <div class="slid-container">
                            <ul class="slickImage" ng-if="loadSwiper" ng-init="previewAd.loadSwiperImages()">
                                <li ng-repeat="image in ads.adDetailForPreview.MainAdsImages track by $index">
                                    <div class="block-cont">
                                        <img ng-class="IsRegularSizeAd?'':'DoubleSizeImg'" ng-src="~/Content/Images/AdsImages/{{image.Path}}" />
                                    </div>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you have any css linked to this part ? ... overflow anywhere ?

Comment: No I have  not linked css to this part

Answer (score 0):

There is an issue using images under div with slick carousel.

You can fix it using flexbox or absolute position.

**with absolute position** :

```
.slid-container{
  position: relative;
}

.slickImage{
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  width: XXX;
  height: XXX;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

**with flexbox** :

```
.slickImage{
  display: flex
  align-items: center
  justify-content: center
  width: XXX;
  height: XXX;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In desktop mode I want to display three image like this

[image]

but in responsive I have to display only single image but it display three images also in responsive

[image]

**View :**

```
 <div class="slider-section2" style="overflow:hidden">
                        <div class="slid-container">
                            <ul class="slickImage" ng-if="loadSwiper" ng-init="previewAd.loadSwiperImages()">
                                <li ng-repeat="image in ads.adDetailForPreview.MainAdsImages track by $index">
                                    <div class="block-cont">
                                        <img ng-class="IsRegularSizeAd?'':'DoubleSizeImg'" ng-src="~/Content/Images/AdsImages/{{image.Path}}" />
                                    </div>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
</div>
</div>
```

**Jquery:**

```
$(".slickImage").slick({
                    centerMode: true,
                    infinite: true,
                    autoplay: false,
                    centerPadding: '0px',
                    slidesToShow: 1,
                    arrows: true
                });
```

any one have an solution to fix this?